# Issue with Java version in AsterixDB

Tags: java, version

I am trying the installation of AsterixDB and see that Java version 8 is not compatible on starting the cluster.
Although in the documentation I see that this version should work.
https://asterixdb.apache.org/docs/0.9.2/install.html

If your version is at least 1.8.0_x, similar to the output shown below, you are good to proceed.

My version is 1.8.0_311.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the documentation for an old version, but if you are installing the latest version of AsterixDB (0.9.7.1), please try Java 11 or more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Oracle 1.8.0_60.